# Can i cast SimpleSQLiteQuery object to DataSource.Factory<key, value> and than LiveData<PagedList<>?

Tags: java, android, android-livedata

Hello i have two classes

First:

```
public class SortUtils {

    public enum Coffesortby {
        CAFFEINE, TYPE, DEFAULT
    }
    
    public static SimpleSQLiteQuery getAllQuery(Coffesortby sortBy, Boolean showOnlyFavorites) {
        SupportSQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder =
                SupportSQLiteQueryBuilder.builder(DataCoffeNames.TABLE_NAME)
                .orderBy(getSortColumn(sortBy));
        if (showOnlyFavorites) {
            queryBuilder.selection(DataCoffeNames.COL_FAVORITE, new String[]{"1"});
        }
        return new SimpleSQLiteQuery(queryBuilder.create().getSql());
    }
    
    private static String getSortColumn(Coffesortby value) {
        switch (value) {
            case CAFFEINE:
                return DataCoffeNames.COL_CAFFEINE;
            case TYPE:
                return DataCoffeNames.COL_TYPE;
            default:
                return DataCoffeNames.COL_NAME;
        }
    }
}
```

and another class with this function:

```
    public LiveData<PagedList<Coffe>> getSortedCoffes(String sort, Boolean fileByFavorite) {
        SortUtils.Coffesortby sortBy = SortUtils.Coffesortby.valueOf(sort);
        DataSource.Factory<Integer, Tea> factory = mDao.getAll(SortUtils.getAllQuery(sortBy, fileByFavorite));
        return new LivePagedListBuilder<>(factory, PAGE_SIZE)
                .build();
    }
```

and CoffeDAO(i'm using RoomDB) with this query script:

```
  @Query(" select * from coffe ")
    DataSource.Factory<Integer, Coffe> getAll();
```

and i want to use getAllQuery function to get sorted query an finally using second class funciton called getSortedCoffes return LiveData<PagedList>, but i don't know how to do it right way..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query(" select * from coffe ")
fun getAll(): PagingSource<Int, Coffe>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.